# If UID=1000 continues, else exit

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am wondering how to implement the following in a bash script.

```
if UID=1000, continue
else exit
confirm choice (y/n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ $UID -ne 1000 ] && exit     # exit if UID ist not equal 1000
```

Comment: This is a good solution too and works for the OP's question, but note that it does not work in `sh` (not relevant here but relevant in general).

Comment: :) For all friends of `sh` and portable code: `[ "$(id -u)" != 1000 ] && exit`

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "1000" ]; then
     do stuff for user 1000
else
     do stuff for other users
fi
```

However, it would probably be more effective to `chown` the script to that user and then `chmod 700`, since it appears from your example that you are attempting to stop execution of the script for other users. This would also give you more control i.e. allowing you to use groups (w/ `chmod 750` or whatever) to manage who can perform the action. If only part of your script should be accessible to user 1000 you can separate that part into its own script and apply permissions appropriately.